# How to loop through lists more efficiently?

Tags: python, list, search

I have two lists at hand, each consisting of tuples in form [(lemma, PoS, token)]. List A is generated by a lemmatizer from input text; List B is from a preexisting database.

The objective is to: check if a token from List A is found in List B, then:
if found, return corresponding lemmas from both lists and check if they are the same, write YES if so, NO if not;
if not found, return corresponding lemma from List A.

Ideally, the output should be something like:

| Token from List A | Lemma from list A | Token found in B? | Lemma from List B? | Same lemma? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sé | ég | YES | ég | YES |
| skór | skó | YES | skór | NO |
| Keplerur | Kepler | NO | n/a | n/a |

So, I tried doing that with for loops cause we didn't really learn much else:

```
for l, pos, t in list_a:
    for seq in list_b:
        if t == seq[2]:
            if pos == seq[1]:
                if l == seq[0]:
                    comparison.append((t,l,"YES",seq[0],"YES"))
            elif pos == seq[1]:
                if l != seq[0]:
                    comparison.append((t,l,"YES",seq[0],"NO"))
            elif pos != seq[1]:
                comparison.append((t,l,"NO","na,"na"))
        elif t != seq[2]:
            comparison.append((t,l,"NO","na","na"))
```

You see, whilst List A is quite short (~120 tuples from the text I am testing on), List B is pre-existing and has >6M elements. For-looping through it for each item on List A is not going to be efficient, I guess. Apparently, my laptop can't complete executing this code anyway, so I can't even test it.

What could I do? I have a feeling a fundamentally different approach is needed here.

UPD: I have, after about an hour of trial and error, come up with this solution:

```
for l, pos, t in lemtok:
    r = next((a for a, b in enumerate(binlistfinal) if b[2] == t), None)
    ind = r
    if r == None:
        comparison.append((t, l, "NO", "n/a", "n/a"))
    else:
        if pos == binlistfinal[ind][1]:
            if l == binlistfinal[ind][0]:
                comparison.append((t, l, "YES", binlistfinal[ind][0], "YES"))
        elif pos != binlistfinal[ind][1]:
            comparison.append((t, l, "NO", "n/a", "n/a"))
        elif pos == binlistfinal[ind][1]:
            if l != binlistfinal[ind][0]:
                comparison.append((t, l, "YES", binlistfinal[ind][0], "NO"))
print(comparison)
```

WHERE:

lemtok is List A, binlistfinal is List B

Comment: Are the tokens unique in list B? Change list B to a dictionary that uses the token as the key.

Comment: I was thinking of that. Unfortunately, neither tokens nor lemmas are unique (lemma-pos-token combinations are).

Comment: 'Apparently, my laptop can't complete executing this code anyway, so I can't even test it.' - what do you mean by this? It's too slow (how slow?) or you run out of memory, or something else?

Comment: Also, please could you provide some sample input?

Comment: @Paul it has been running for well over 15 mins, swap use by the Jupyter-Lab process exceeded 70 Gb (and that's on a 32 Gb RAM laptop). I've never been able to complete the process: even when JL reported it finished, print(comparison) would get it stuck for infinity.

Comment: Is list b sorted in any way?

Comment: Create a new list from ListB with the tuples swapped - i.e., (token, PoS, lemma) - call it ListC. Now sort ListC. Implement a binary search on ListC that provides the index range of matching tokens. Then check elements for that range to see if lemma matches and go from there. The code will be considerably more complex than what you have now but may perform better. Having said that, you should probably have some idea ahead of time about what your performance needs are

Comment: You are comparing every tuple from A to every tuple from B. This means you'll end up with with 120 * 6M entries in your output. Is this what you want,  or do you want 120 entries (i.e. one entry per tuple in A)?

Answer (score 0):

So your current code is O(NM) where N is the size of list A and M is the size of list B.

Assuming list B is not sorted nor does it contain unique tokens, you are going to have to at least iterate through all elements of B once. This makes it O(M).
If we can get the access time of list A down to O(1), then your runtime will still be O(M). Now I will just assume all of the tokens in A are unique since the list is quite short. If it is not, you can just generate a dictionary with tokens as the key, and a list of values that the token is associated with and adjust from there.
Sorting list B will not actually help because best case that will be O(MlogM) which is worse.

Now your code might look like the following:

```
old_a = ...
B = ...
A = {token: (lemma, pos) for token, lemma, pos in old_A}
B_tokens_in_A = set() # store a list of the tokens B tokens found in A which is equal to the A tokens found in B.
for lemma, pos, token in B:
  if token in A:
    B_tokens_in_A.add(token)
    if A[token][0] == lemma:
      # return lemma and write yes
    else:
      # return lemmas and write no
   
# now we need to return the lemmas from list A whose tokens were not in list B
for token, val in A.items():
  if token not in B_tokens_in_A:
    # return lemma from A
```